# Compound queries in Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations) says:

> Queries with a `!=` clause. In this case, you should split the query into a greater-than query and a less-than query. For example, although the query clause `where("age", "!=", "30")` is not supported, you can get the same result set by combining two queries, one with the clause `where("age", "<", "30")` and one with the clause `where("age", ">", 30)`.

I need to grab users that are in certain age range so this seems like a great way for grabbing relevant ones but unfortunately, I apparently don't understand how to use this.

```
    let potentialMatchesRef = db.collection("users")
                                .whereField("isBanned", isEqualTo: false)
                                .whereField("isHidden", isEqualTo: false)
                                .whereField("location.country", isEqualTo: user.location.country)
    potentialMatchesRef
                                .whereField("age", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: user.preferences.ageRange.from)
                                .whereField("age", isLessThanOrEqualTo: user.preferences.ageRange.to)
```

This doesn't work and when I use `where("age", ">", 30)` I get error `Value of type 'Query' has no member 'where'`.

UPDATE: Apparently they don't have dedicated docs for Swift.

If I use this

```
    let potentialMatchesRef = db.collection("users")
                                .whereField("isBanned", isEqualTo: false)
                                .whereField("isHidden", isEqualTo: false)
                                .whereField("location.country", isEqualTo: user.location.country)
                                .whereField("age", isLessThanOrEqualTo: to)
                                .whereField("age", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: from)
```

I get error `Error getting documents: Error Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=9 "The query requires an index.`

There are minimum 2 fields and I can't write age in both. Please, can somebody help.

Comment: Please include the exact error message you get in the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the documentation says you can "combine two queries", that means you should be making two completely different queries, executing them separately, and combining the results on the client to come up with the final set of documents.

What you're trying to do is make a single query with two clauses that filter on age.  This won't work, because all the conditions in a single query are logically AND'd together (there are currently no logical OR queries in Firestore).  Think about it this way - the set of documents where "age is > 30 AND age < 30" is always going to yield 0 documents because any value for age can't satisfy both of those requirements.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. But would be an awesome feature in Firestore tho.

Comment: You can always file feature requests here: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: I don't know when they were introduced, but as for 2020 OR queries are supported if your document field is an array. In Swift you can use the operators `arrayContainsAny:` and `in:`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#swift_6

Comment: @jackdbd That only helps if the things you're looking for are in a single field.  It doesn't work when the data spans different fields.